# Trying to write a custom loader for pig that processes records spanning multiple line, how to make sure splits don't happen in the middle of records?

Tags: java, hadoop, split, apache-pig

I'm writing a custom Loader for pig. It is supposed to read delimited records that might span into multiple lines. Everything works, except that sometimes a split happens in the middle of a record and messes everything. I know RecordReader and InputFormat have to do with the place the files are split, but can't figure out how to make it work in my case. 
To me, it looks like the CSVExcelStorage should have the same problem, but I can't find any code to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

CSVExcelStorage works on the assumption that there aren't any embedded new line characters and so there's no code that handles them.

You're right about RecordReader being the culprit here.  You'll need to write a new record reader class that understands your data and therefore understands which new line characters are candidates for a split location and which new line chars are simply part of the data.  Once you write a new record class, you'll need a new InputFormatType to use that record reader class.

Comment: The [CSVExcelStorage](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.java) states that it supports multiline fields though.